# Need help on php arrays from mysql data to be summarized

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Pulling data from MySQL tables, data looks like:

```
Acct #          Acct Name                  Item     Date Sold            Qty Sold 
10293           Company A               Canon JX200 2012-06-24                1
11042           Company B               Canon JX200 2012-06-05                2
12560           Company D               Canon L90   2012-04-20                1
12560           Company D               Canon L90   2012-05-07                1
14160           Company D               Canon L90   2012-05-22                2
14168           Company C               Canon L90   2012-04-20                6
```

I want output that looks like:

```
Acct #  Acct Name   Item          Mo 1  Mo 2    Mo 3    Mo 4    Mo 5    Mo 6    Tot
10293   Company A   Canon JX200                                           1       1
11042   Company B   Canon JX200                                           2       2
12560   Company C   Canon L90                             6                       6
12560   Company D   Canon L90                             1       3               4
```

Aced 2 Linear Algebra classes in college and php arrays have me stumped. Need to put my data into array, sort and summarize. Biggest problem (I think) is code to structure the array. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use pivot table. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MySQL/Pivot_table

Answer (score 0):

try to sort data in MySQL query by addinf ORDER BY *Acct Name*. When you recieve the data this code should help:

```
$data = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
preg_match('/^\d{4}\-(\d{2})\-/', $row['DateSold'], $match);
  $data[] = array(
   'Acct' => $row['Acct'],
   'AcctName' => $row['AcctName'],
   'Item' => $row['Item'],
   'Mo ' . $match[1] => $row['QtySold']
  );

}
```